# Strange C++ errors with code that has min()/max() calls

Tags: c++, c

I'm seeing strange errors when my C++ code has min() or max() calls. I'm using Visual C++ compilers.

Comment: This is officially the oddest question on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check if your code is including the **windows.h** header file and either your code or other third-party headers have their own **min()**/**max()** definitions. If yes, then prepend your **windows.h** inclusion with a definition of **NOMINMAX** like this:

```
#define NOMINMAX
#include <windows.h>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility could be from side effects.  Most min/max macros will include the parameters multiple times and may not do what you expect.  Errors and warnings could also be generated.

```
max(a,i++) expands as ((a) > (i++) ? (a) : (i++))
```

afterwards i is either plus 1 or plus 2

The () in the expansion are to avoid problems if you call it with formulae.  Try expanding max(a,b+c)

Answer (score 2):

Since Windows defines this as a function-style macro, the following workaround is available:

```
int i = std::min<int>(3,5);
```

This works because the macro `min()` is expanded only when `min` is followed by `(`, and not when it's followed by `<`.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh... scope it, dude: `std::min()`, `std::max()`.

Comment: You still need to #define NOMINMAX or the preprocessor will still expand min & max.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it in years but from memory boost assigns min and max too, possibly?

Answer (score -1):

Honestly, when it comes to min/max, I find it best to just define my own:

```
#define min(a,b) ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))
#define max(a,b) ((a) >= (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

Comment: Which, frankly, is asking for trouble.  In C++, use `using std::swap` and write your own swap when you can do better than the default.  In C, at the very lease write `#define min(a,b) ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))` and MAKE SURE YOU DON'T CALL IT WITH ANYTHING WITH SIDE EFFECTS, because you will have multiple evaluation.