# Compiler not recognizing custom numeric_limits member function

Tags: c++, templates, stl, compiler-errors, numeric-limits

I'm using a data structure that wants to use STL `limits` to determine the min, max, and infinity (I think only these) values of a struct I'm giving it.  I'm using Visual C++ 2010, if there is implementation specific details for this stuff.

Here's the basic structure of my data types, with `PseudoTuple::ReturnWrapper` being the type needing limits support:

```
struct PseudoTuple
{
 struct ReturnWrapper
 {
  //wraps return values for comparisons and such
 }

 typedef ReturnWrapper value_type;

 //basic "tuple" implementation as a data front
}
```

With the power of copy and paste, I created a small `numeric_limits` class for it, implementing only the 3 functions I think are required.  The return values are currently temporary, just to see if this will compile.

```
namespace std
{
 template<> class _CRTIMP2_PURE numeric_limits<PseudoTuple::ReturnWrapper>
  : public _Num_int_base
 {
 public:
  typedef PseudoTuple::ReturnWrapper _Ty;

  static _Ty (__CRTDECL min)() _THROW0()
  { // return minimum value
   return PseudoTuple::ReturnWrapper();
  }

  static _Ty (__CRTDECL max)() _THROW0()
  { // return maximum value
   return PseudoTuple::ReturnWrapper();
  }

  static _Ty __CRTDECL infinity() _THROW0()
  { // return positive infinity
   return PseudoTuple::ReturnWrapper();
  }
 };
}

#include <data structure using PseudoTuple>
```

And I include the header after this to make sure it can grab these declarations.  I'm getting an error in it here:

```
namespace detail {

 template<typename coordinate_type, bool is_integer, bool has_infinity>
 struct coordinate_limits_impl;

 template<typename coordinate_type>
 struct coordinate_limits_impl<coordinate_type, true, false> {
  static const coordinate_type highest() {
   return std::numeric_limits<coordinate_type>::max(); // --- error here ---
  }
  static const coordinate_type lowest() {
   return std::numeric_limits<coordinate_type>::min();
  }
 };

//lots of stuff

}
```

`coordinate_type` is a typedef of `PseudoTuple::ReturnWrapper`.  Here's the error:

```
error C2589: '(' : illegal token on right side of '::'
error C2059: syntax error : '::'
```

And also getting this interesting warning on all uses of `min` and `max`, this one being on the same line as the error:

```
warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'max'
```

When I use this data structure with an `std::array` of `std::string`, I still get those warnings but no compiler errors pop up.  It also runs properly in that case, so the whole thing must work somehow.  But it doesn't recognize the `max` function when using my custom `numeric_limits`.

If I change the `max()` to `infinity()`, it compiles fine and moves on to throwing an error on `min()`.  The names `min` and `max` are giving it some grief, but I'm not sure why.  This does tell me that it can grab the `infinity` method from my implementation of `numeric_limits`, though.

edit: Removed data structure code showing the right type is being passed in, seems irrelevant.

edit 2: Mark B solved the problem, but a new one popped up:

`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static struct PseudoTuple::ReturnWrapper __cdecl std::numeric_limits<struct PseudoTuple::ReturnWrapper>::max(void)" (__imp_?max@?$numeric_limits@UReturnWrapper@PseudoTuple@@@std@@SA?AUReturnWrapper@PseudoTuple@@XZ) referenced in function "public: static struct PseudoTuple::ReturnWrapper const __cdecl kd_v1_0_8::spatial::detail::coordinate_limits_impl<struct PseudoTuple::ReturnWrapper,1,0>::highest(void)" (?highest@?$coordinate_limits_impl@UReturnWrapper@PseudoTuple@@$00$0A@@detail@spatial@kd_v1_0_8@@SA?BUReturnWrapper@PseudoTuple@@XZ)`

So something is messing up the linking...  Getting the same for `min` but not for `infinity`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I deal with the `max` macro in windows.h colliding with `max` in `std`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544073/how-do-i-deal-with-the-max-macro-in-windows-h-colliding-with-max-in-std)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes `min` and `max` were implemented as macros which just substitute text. It's not your specialization that's causing issues here but the macros. I believe `windows.h` is one such offender. You can use `#define NOMINMAX` to cause them to not be created as macros.

Comment: Nice call, but apparently my specialization isn't so amazing.  Getting a linker error now.  It's too long to paste into this box, I have it edited to the end of the OP above.