# struct as parameter causing "mismatch in formal parameter list"

Tags: c++, struct

Hi I'm having a problem using a `struct` as a parameter.

My struct looks the following:

```
typedef struct temps {
    string name;
    float max;
} temps;
```

I can use it in my main without problems like:

```
temps t;
t.max = 1.0;
```

but using it in a function signatures like this:

```
void printTemps(const temps& t) {
    cout << t.name << endl << "MAX: " << t.max << endl;
}
```

It gives me the following compiler message:

> error C2563: mismatch in formal parameter list

Here is a mwe:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Lmcons.h>

using namespace std;

typedef struct temps {
    string name;
    float max;
} temps;

void printTemps(const temps& t) {
    cout << t.name << endl << "MAX: " << t.max << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    temps t;
    t.max = 1.0;
    printTemps(t);
}
```

Any ideas whats wrong on the struct?

Comment: Don't use typedef struct in C++. Show the compiler error message.

Comment: Which headers and using statements did you use? Please post a full [mcve].

Comment: I put `#include<iostream>` and `using namespace std;` at the top and it compiled fine on g++ 6.3.0

Comment: just added the includes. sry for that

Comment: Which compiler and version? It works for me on MSVC 2017.

Comment: Included string and fstream, works fine on Ubuntu 17.04, no warnings or errors even with -Wall. Can't test with windows headers.

Comment: @rex same for me but getting the error

Comment: @user2798895 does MCVE you posted compile without windows.h and Lmcons.h?

Comment: I created a fresh project and it compiled without warnings.

Comment: Is there a max() macro still in the windows headers? I am thinking of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544073/how-do-i-deal-with-the-max-macro-in-windows-h-colliding-with-max-in-std

Comment: @drescherjm using the name of a function-like macro without `(` following it, does not invoke the macro

Answer (score -1):

You're using the C typedef struct declaration.

```
typedef struct temps {
    string name;
    float max;
} temps;

//void printTemps(const temps& t) {
void printTemps(const struct temps& t) {  // should match the C idiom
    cout << t.name << endl << "MAX: " << t.max << endl;
}
```

But since you are programming in C++, you should use the C++ way of declaring structs.

```
struct temps {
    string name;
    float max;
};

void printTemps(const temps& t) {
    cout << t.name << '\n' << "MAX: " << t.max << '\n';  // using \n is more efficient
}                                                        // since std::endl 
                                                         // flushes the stream
```

Comment: It's true that OP should avoid the typedef, however the typedef makes no change to the program (and therefore this change wouldn't fix the problem, unless the compiler is bugged or OP has not posted the real code, which is probably the case).