# C++ unrecognizable template declaration/definition

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2019

I have a project using CMake. The following code builds fine on Apple Clang, MinGW, and Android Cross-Clang but does not build on VS2019:

```
template<typename Ty> constexpr Ty min(const Ty& _a, const Ty& _b);
```

Visual Studio produces three errors for the same line:

```
Error   C2988   unrecognizable template declaration/definition
Error   C2059   syntax error: 'const'
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'
```

I feel like it's due to a setting, but Visual Studio is set to use the v142 toolchain and use the latest available C++ standard.

Comment: Visual studio headers (at least *some* versions) have macros defining `min` and `max` (yeah, horrible) , may that be what's tripping you up?

Comment: Can you make a [mre] that reproduces the issue?

Comment: That was it @JesperJuhl - putting `#undef min` and `#undef max` above it sorted it out. Is there a way to disable VS defining those anyhow?

Comment: Bart:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544073/how-do-i-deal-with-the-max-macro-in-windows-h-colliding-with-max-in-std

Comment: @BartPelle I Don't know, sorry. I try to stay away from Microsoft products, so I don't know details

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you! And understandable Jesper - this had me confused as well mainly because of the extremely vague error... Thanks for the pointers!