# Template class derived from a base template class: error C2059: syntax error: '('

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, syntax-error, c++17

There is derived class `BoundingBox3Base`:

```cpp
template <class PointClass>
class BoundingBox3Base : public BoundingBoxBase<PointClass>
{
public:
BoundingBox3Base(const std::vector<PointClass>& points)
    {
        // ...
        
        // ** Error happens at this line:
        // ** error C2059: syntax error: '('
        this->defined = (this->min(0) < this->max(0)) && (this->min(1) < this->max(1)) && (this->min(2) < this->max(2));
    }
};
```

Derived from a base class `BoundingBoxBase`:

```cpp
template <class PointClass>
class BoundingBoxBase
{
public:
    PointClass min;
    PointClass max;
    bool defined;

    BoundingBoxBase(const std::vector<PointClass>& points) : min(PointClass::Zero()), max(PointClass::Zero())
    {
        if (points.empty()) {
            this->defined = false;
            
        } else {
            // ...
            
            this->defined = (this->min(0) < this->max(0)) && (this->min(1) < this->max(1));
        }
    }
};
```

I'm receiving this compile error at the marked** line:

> error C2059: syntax error: '('

I cannot figure out what I'm missing! Can anybody help?

### RESOLVED

The issue got resolved by suppressing the min and max definitions in `Windef.h` by defining `NOMINMAX` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11544154/3405291).

Comment: Can't [reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/9bGT55). Please add the compiler, and language version.

Comment: @cigien MSVC 2017 (C++17)

Comment: For me it compiled, *after* added a `;` after class declaration

Comment: @Damien Copy-paste mistake, added `;`

Comment: You don't call the base class constructor; we do need to see more of your code so we can try to reproduce the error. As it is, we cannot answer this. Also, where do you instantiate the template?

Comment: I used gcc 7.4.0

Comment: @Damien Thanks. For some reason, I'm receiving the error. Might be related to more of my code ...

Comment: Please show the class definition for the *actual* type you use as the `PointClass` template parameter.  Does it have a suitable `operator()` member defined?

Comment: Given that others can't reproduce the syntax error, this is likely in the surrounding code. Try to create a minimal reproducible example. 

This also reeks of macros. examine your preprocessor output.

Comment: My crystal ball says that you have `#include<windows.h>` and that the infamous [`min`/`max` macros](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11544073/8586227) have you.

Comment: @DavisHerring Thanks! I didn't check yet! Let me check when I'm back =)

Comment: @DavisHerring I double-checked! You were absolutely right =)