# Is "small" a keyword in c?

Tags: c, header-files, identifier

This is the first code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
    int small;//showing error-(two or more data type in declaration specifiers
}
```

This is the second code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int small;//normal declaration without any error
}
```

Whenever I include header file `<conio.h>`  then declaring a identifier "small" gives an error, why?
I am using `mingw gcc` compiler and `codeblocks` ide

Also I have added following code in `<conio.h>`

```
#include <windows.h>
void gotoxy(short int col,short int row)
{
    HANDLE hStdout=GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD position={col,row};
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdout,position);
}
```

after removing above code from `<conio.h>`

```
int small;
```

works even after including `<conio.h>`.

Comment: No, but it might be a typedef or #define in your conio.h. why not have a look?

Comment: This makes me suspect conio.h or something it includes defines "small" as a macro. That would not be good.

Comment: http://brickos.sourceforge.net/docs/APIs/html-c/conio_8h-source.html
there is no "small" word in the source. wonder why you are getting this error...

Comment: i have edited the code...please see again

Comment: Perhaps this is pertinent: http://bugs.python.org/issue14387

Comment: what IDE are you using, since you are including `conio.h`, chances are you have VS installed, but codeblocks or in fact most IDE's allow you to ctrl + click a word to see its definition...

Comment: i am using codeblocks

Comment: Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5874215/10077

Comment: A `typedef` would not cause this problem; only a macro would.

Comment: If its too difficult to read through the header files, you can use this kind of checking: 
`#ifdef small` /
`#error 'small' is defined as a macro` /
`#endif`

Answer (score 8):

I guarantee that `small` is *not* a keyword in C. If it were, the presence or absence of a `#include` directive would not make any difference.

The problem is that `<windows.h>` stupidly defines `small` as a macro. (Other answers and comments suggest it might be a `typedef`, but that wouldn't explain the problem you're seeing.)

I'm able to reproduce the problem on my system (Cygwin, Windows 7, compiling with `mingw32-gcc`, which is installed as part of the Cygwin package). Presumably the same thing would happen with MinGW installed separately from Cygwin.

First of all, `<conio.h>` is a (non-standard) header provided by the implementation. You almost certainly shouldn't be trying to modify it. You *definitely* shouldn't be adding a function definition to a header file (function definitions belong in `.c` files, not in `.h` files). If you want to write your own `gotoxy` function, declare it in your own header and define it in your own `.c` file; don't mess around with the implementation. (B

But when you added your `gotoxy` function to `<conio.h>`, you also added

```
#include <windows.h>
```

Here's a small program that illustrates the problem:

```
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
    int small;
}
```

When I compile this with `mingw32-gcc`, I get:

```
c.c: In function 'main':
c.c:4:9: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
c.c:4:5: warning: useless type name in empty declaration [enabled by default]
```

Digging further, it turns out that `<windows.h>` includes `<rpcndr.h>`, which contains the following:

```
#define small char
```

So every occurrence of the identifier `small` in any C source that has `#include <windows.h>` will be replaced by the keyword `char` -- which, in your case, will cause a syntax error.

A handy way to find things like this: `gcc` has a `-E` option that causes it to show the output of the compiler's preprocessor phase.  With the above program, I tried this:

```
$ mingw32-gcc -E c.c | tail



#pragma pack(pop)
# 115 "c:\\gnustep\\bin\\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/windows.h" 2 3
# 2 "c.c" 2
int main()
{
    int char;
}
$
```

which shows how the `int short;` declaration was mangled by the preprocessor.

To be clear, this is entirely the fault of the maintainers of `<windows.h>` and `<rpcndr.h>`. `small` is a perfectly valid C identifier, and a system header absolutely should not define it as a macro. `typedef char small;` would have served the same purpose and not caused this problem. Others have had [similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14165/827263) with `<windows.h>` defining macros `min` and `max`. That can be worked around with:

```
#define NOMINMAX
#include <windows.h>
```

but as far as I can tell there's no such workaround for `small`.

Incidentally, `rpcndr.h` also defines `hyper`.

The simplest solution is to call your variable something other than `small` -- and hope you don't collide with other macros defined in `<windows.h>`.  Or you can add

```
#undef small
```

before the declaration. You *shouldn't* need to do either of these things, but thanks to poorly written system headers, such workaround are sometimes necessary.

Or just avoid including `<windows.h>` (that's not always possible).

(You could modify your copy of the `rpcndr.h` file, but I advise against doing so; it's likely to cause other problems, and your code still won't compile on a system where `rpcndr.h` hasn't been hacked.)

**UPDATE :** This may have been corrected. I don't see the error using `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` under Cygwin on Windows 10. Perhaps someone else who uses mingw can investigate further.

Comment: Nice _small_ answer.  Can't deny 'entirely the fault of the maintainers of `<windows.h>`".

Comment: to avoid including `windows.h` one can create a wrapper for the needed functions and just include `windows.h` in that module

Answer (score 4):

No. There is no keyword like `small` in standard C. This may be a macro in `<conio.h>`.

#### C11: 6.4.1 Keywords:

> keyword: one of
>
> ```
> auto 
> break
> case
> char
> const
> continue
> default
> do
> double
> else
> enum
> extern
> float
> for
> goto
> if
> inline
> int
> long
> register
> restrict
> return
> short
> signed
> sizeof
> static
> struct
> switch
> typedef
> union
> unsigned
> void
> volatile
> while
> _Alignas
> _Alignof
> _Atomic
> _Bool
> _Complex
> _Generic
> _Imaginary
> _Noreturn
> _Static_assert
> _Thread_local
> ```

Comment: It may also be defined in a header `#include`d in `conio.h` but not in `stdio.h`.

Comment: @haccks: is there any explanation for this query?

Comment: I do not understand the last added part of your answer.

Comment: i am just asking whether there is any explanation for the above query

Comment: I have limited knowledge and I can't say that is there exist any explanation for the above query.

Answer (score 2):

I found it...
its a macro defined in some header file which is included in `windows.h`.

as i have included `windows.h` in `conio.h` so in my program it is automatically included when i include `conio.h`.

I Found it by ctrl + clicking on `small`

Answer (score 0):

There is no such keyword, but check if it is `typedef`ed somewhere.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's `typedef`ed. If it were, the declaration `int small;` in an inner scope would be perfectly legal, and would hide the `typedef`. It's more likely to be a macro.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be the fault of MinGW. The same error appears with `large`.

Comment: I was reading here: http://www.gecode.org/pipermail/users/2013-January/003763.html

Comment: "Int "large" was modified to "large_" purely for aesthetic reasons"

sorry :P

Comment: after removing the `void gotoxy()` from `conio.h` , `int small;` works fine

Comment: @learner: You'll still have the same problem if you `#include <windows.h>`. And `conio.h` is provided by your implementation; you shouldn't be modifying it.

Answer (score 0):

By adding `#include <windows.h>`, you are pulling in a lot of other header files. [One problem that has been reported](http://bugs.python.org/issue14387) is of it defining a preprocessor macro "small". It has also been discussed in another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5874215/10077).

One workaround is to add `#undef small` after you `#include <windows.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

Just define `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` macro in code or VS Properties dialog and the problem will be gone:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
```