# compiler error C2059: syntax error 'type'

Tags: c, visual-c++, compiler-errors, inline

Using MSVC 2013, I'm getting the error:

```
compiler error C2059: syntax error 'type'
```

for

```
inline double min ( double a, double b ) { return a < b ? a : b; }
```

I fail to see what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Visual C++ does not support the `inline` keyword, so simply remove it and it should work. Or you can use `__inline`, but it's not standard.

Comment: That is partially correct. The VC++ does not support `inline` for C. I know the question is tagged `C`, however, people may read your answer and think that the C++ compiler in Visual Studio does not support this keyword. So I wanted to make this clarification. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88.aspx for references.

Comment: Never even tried `inline` with the MS C compiler before.  Who knew? (trick question; apparently *you* and Marius did). If `windows.h` is slurped I *think* you still have to #define NOMINMAX ([ala this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165/strange-c-errors-with-code-that-has-min-max-calls)) if you do this. I don't have a winbox handy so I can't verify that.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `min` is already defined as a macro by standard Windows headers:

```
#define min(a,b)            (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
```

replace `min` by `mymin` and it will compile fine or write:

```
#undef min
inline double min ( double a, double b ) { return a < b ? a : b; }
```